# Subquery / embedded multiple joins?

Tags: sql, join, odbc, self-join

Firstly apologies if this is a duplicate - I'm not quite sure what the correct terminology is for what I'm trying to achieve, so may have missed an implementation in other posts.

Need a query which acting on a single table (being called through ODBC to either MySQL or Oracle) that mimics a file based system.

Logic is to return the latest version of an item. The latest is defined over a composite key of VERSION and DRAFT.

pseudo logic is

```
    for each document (
       find highest VERSION
          for each VERSION (
             find highest DRAFT (
                Add item to list
             )
           )
        )
     )
```

I would like to know if there's a way to achieve this with one query with embedded self selects or joins or (sorry this is where the terminology bit breaks down)

I have attempted:

```
CREATE TABLE docs
    (
        TYPE        varchar(20) NOT NULL,
        ID          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        VERSION     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        DRAFT       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL

    );
    
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc1', ' ', 'A') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc1', ' ', 'B') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc1', '1', ' ') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc1', '1', 'A') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc1', '2', ' ') ;

INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc2', ' ', 'A') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc2', ' ', 'B') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc2', '1', ' ') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc2', '1', 'A') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc2', '2', ' ') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc2', '2', 'A') ;

INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc3', ' ', 'A') ;

INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc4', ' ', 'A') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('REQ','doc4', '1', ' ') ;

INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('TEST','doc1', ' ', 'A') ;
INSERT INTO docs (TYPE, ID, VERSION, DRAFT) VALUES ('TEST','doc1', '1', ' ') ;
```

---

```
select * from docs items
        inner join  ((select ID as vID, max(VERSION) as ver from docs group by ID) vers
            inner join  (select ID as dID, VERSION as dver, max(DRAFT) as dft from docs group by ID, VERSION) drfts
                on (vers.vID = drfts.dID and vers.ver = drfts.dver))
            on items.ID = vers.vID
     where TYPE='REQ'  order by ID;
```

But I do not get the results expected. Any guidance as to what topic / method I should investigate would be appreciated.

---

Edit: response to comment

Desired output:

doc1,2,' '
doc2,2,'a'
doc3,' ','a'
doc4,1,' '

Comment: Since you have created the date, which is really helpful to find an answer, you could provide a desired output from your data. It would help a lot to formulate a solution.

Comment: Thanks, the desired output would be doc1,2,' ' doc2,2,'a', doc3,' ','a' and doc4,1,' '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Logic is to return the latest version of an item. The latest is defined over a composite key of VERSION and DRAFT.

Use window functions.  The following returns one row per document, the row with the highest version and then for that version, the highest draft:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc, draft desc) as seqnum
      from docs d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```